# How to create numpy.ndarray A from existing B using various functions depending on corresponding value in B?

Tags: python, numpy

I have `numpy.ndarray` **A** with shape S. I want to create `numpy.ndarray` **B** with same shape but different value type. Also, I want to use various functions to transform element of **A** into corresponding element of **B**, but it's guaranteed that return type of all these functions will be the same.

Long story short, I would like to do something like this:

```
def func1():
    return np.zeros(5)

def func2():
    return np.ones(5)

def func(val):
    return func2() if val & 1 else func1()

A = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 10))
B = np.array((10, 10, 5))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        B[i, j] = func(A[i, j])
```

What is the most efficient/elegant way to do such an operation using numpy?

I tried to use functions from paragraph "Functional programming" from numpy's API Reference, but they either do not work piecewise or do not support change of value type.

**P.S.** Problem solved thanks to @bill. We can apply `func` to whole row at once using `np.apply_along_axis`.

Comment: In your title you have "How to create numpy.ndarray A ..." but in your example you're setting array B. Also, does array B have `shape=(10, 10, 5)`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely B has `shape=(10, 10, 5)` because I want to construct `np.ndarray` with `shape=(5)` from every element of A.

Comment: `if/else only works with scalar values, not with arrays.  But you can construct a 'mask' of elements where you want to use `func1` etc.  Using a 'mask' to selectively perform an action on part of an array should be a standard part of your numpy toolbox.

Comment: But how to selectively perform an operation on array if the return type of func1 isn't equal to base type (in this case, `np.intc` isn't equal to `np.array` with `shape=(5)` of `np.intc`)?

Comment: Did you mean `B = np.empty((10, 10, 5))` instead of `B = np.array((10, 10, 5))`?

Comment: I don't see how `apply_along_axis` is useful.  It passes a 1d array to the function.  But your `func` only works with scalar values, not 10 element 1d arrays (e.g. a row of `A`).  Even where it works it doesn't have a speed benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't execute (IndexError) so it's hard to know what you want to do exactly.

Is this what you wanted?

```
B = np.where(A & 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: It seems useful, but is there a way to pass callable as 2nd and 3rd argument to np.where?

Comment: `where` takes array arguments, not callables.  It isn't an iterator in the sense of your `func`.

Comment: I see. In that case you might want to try [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Comment: Okay, I revised it's description and now I understand how to use it for my task. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setup input data (to create B, where B has shape `(2, 2, 5)`)

```py
A = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])

output_true = [1,3,5,7,9] # to be selected when condition is true
output_false = [0,2,4,6,8] # to be selected when condition is false
```

First broadcast your input data to the desired output shape

```
# Tell numpy where the new dimension is to be added to the input data. 
input_data = np.broadcast_to(A.reshape((2, 2, 1)), (2, 2, 5))
# array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
#
#        [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#         [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
# N.B. `reshape()` copies the data, which can make it a potentially expensive
# operation. Setting the `shape` attribute instead does not. eg:
A.shape = (2, 2, 1)
input_data = np.broadcast_to(A, (2, 2, 5))
A.shape = (2, 2)  # return A to its original shape
```

Then use `input_data` to create a mask that selects which of the two outputs you wish to select. Here we're going to test whether an element is odd.

```py
mask = input_data & 1
# array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
#
#        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int32)
```

Use `np.where()` to use `mask` and  your outputs to create `B`.

```py
B = np.where(mask, output_true, output_false)
# here each row is one of the "output" rows, and satifies the condition:
# B[M,N] == ([1,3,5,7,9] if odd(A[N,M]) else [0,2,4,6,8])
# array([[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
#         [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]],
#
#        [[0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
#         [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]])
```

For the sake of efficiency, you might want to try creating the mask first, and then broadcasting it to the desired shape.